# Pdf thumbnail wordpress

Tags: php, pdf, plugins, wordpress

I'm using WordPress and I want to include some PDF documents. I don't want to put links, I want to make a picture of it and below it to write a title, short content or anything simple that looks good.
for example like this:
[image: Example]  or like in this link [Example](http://swapno-bd.org/beta/media/publications/).

I searched for a plugin but I couldn't find one that makes this? I tried some but nothing useful? Can somebody give me any idea or any name of a plugin ?  Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you inserted the image on your Example link, some fancy box shortcode?  You need to a link as shown below that points to your PDF file instead of the fancy-box pop-up.  I don't use fancy box, do they give you an option to specify a target link for an image?

```
<a target="_blank" href="/path/to/downloadfile.pdf" class="image">
    <img width="50" height="55" alt="" src="http://swapno-bd.org/beta/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Trg-Rights-Entitlement.jpg">
</a>
```